# Python AzureML Hello world - Can't find module azureml

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk, azuremlsdk

Python 3.10, Pip install azureml-sdk 1.39.0.
Environments: Win10 PS, VS2022, and a docker image- all same results . Pip show shows the azureml-core package.

Simple (I thought) script, but it can't find "azureml.core"   No module named azureml is the error.
How do I make it "find" it? I'm new at python so it could be syntax.

```
import os
from azureml.core import Workspace, Experiment, Environment, Model,Dataset,Datastore,ScriptRunConfig
     
    # check core SDK version number
    print("Azure ML SDK Version: ", azureml.core.VERSION)
```

Comment: Please share details on how you're running your code, is it inside any type of virtual env like conda?

Comment: This was in a conda environment, but I did find the issue. 
Apparently, I needed to import azureml then from azureml.core import .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

azureml python sdk does not support py3.10 yet, AutoML sdk supports py<=3.8.